# SQL/VBA INSERT INTO SELECT Statement, Data from 2 or more tables into one

Tags: sql, database, vba, select, insert-into

- I have a table1 (**tblPurchaseOrders**) and a table2
  (**tblPurchaseOrderDetails**).
- The table 1 contains **PurchaseOrder_ID**, Supplier_FK, Employee_FK,
  **Status**  which contains 2 records (New and Done). The table2 contains PurchaseOrder_FK, **Product_FK**, **Quantity** and Price.
- I made a Form (from table1) and a sub-form in it (from table 2). The
  Main form is the Purchase Order (frmPurchaseOrder) and the sub-form
  (frmPurchaseOrderDetails) contains all the products purchased with
  that purchase order,

```css
tblPurchaseOrder.PurchaseOrder_ID = tblPurchaseOrderDetails.PurchaseOrder_FK
```

- I want to take PurchaseOrder_ID and Status from table1, Product_FK
  and Quantity from table 2 and put all the records into a table3
  tblStockMovements. Not just one record but all of them with the
  statement above. So when I open the main Form, lets say the
  PurchaseOrder_ID is "10" and the Status is "Done" and in the sub-form
  there are 2 records:

  1. record 1) Product_FK "Nokia N8", Quantity "10";
  2. record 2) Product_FK "Samsung S3", Quantity "20".
- There will be a button in the form which will run the code on click
  and move the above records to tblStockMovements. After clicking the
  button the tblStockMovements will look like on the picture

  [tblStockMovements after button click in main form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJd16.png)

The code I tried is next:

```css
Private Sub cmdOrder_Click()
 
    Dim strSQL As String
 
    strSQL = ""
    strSQL = strSQL & "INSERT INTO tblStockMovement ( "
    strSQL = strSQL & "  Product_FK "
    strSQL = strSQL & ", Status "
    strSQL = strSQL & ", Quantity "
    strSQL = strSQL & ", PurchaseOrder_FK "
    strSQL = strSQL & ") SELECT "
    strSQL = strSQL & "  tblPurchaseOrderDetails.Product_FK "
    strSQL = strSQL & ", tblPurchaseOrder.Status "
    strSQL = strSQL & ", tblPurchaseOrderDetails.Quantity "
    strSQL = strSQL & ", tblPurchaseOrder.PurchaseOrder_ID "
    strSQL = strSQL & "FROM tblPurchaseOrder "
    strSQL = strSQL & "LEFT JOIN tblPurchaseOrderDetails "
    strSQL = strSQL & "ON tblPurchaseOrder.PurchaseOrder_ID= tblPurchaseOrderDetails.PurchaseOrder_FK "
    strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE PurchaseOrder_ID=" & Me!PurchaseOrder_ID
 
    CurrentDB.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError + dbSeeChanges
    Me.Requery
 
End Sub
```

- When I run it I get the error "get the same error "Syntax error in
  FROM clause (3131)" . I tried to add [PurchaseOrdersDetails] in the
  FROM code line but then I get the syntax error in JOIN operation
  (3135)

Comment: Try getting the string from `strSQL`, copy it and use it to run a query in the Access GUI.  It will often give better error messages.

Comment: Solved, was a typo.
`WHERE PurchaseOrder.PurchaseOrder_ID =..`